# drop-down menu on the left sidebar

Tags: html, css, menu, sidebar

I'm trying to make a submenu that appears on the right side of the main menu, I've already made the menu but can't display the submenu correctly, can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

It is better that you upload your code. However i think you mean something like this (try it):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .DropDownMenu-Content {
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 105px;
      display: none;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px lightgreen;
    }
    
    .DropDownMenu-Content a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 1rem;
    }
    
    .DropDownMenu:hover .DropDownMenu-Content { display: block; }
    
    .DropDownBottom {
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 1rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Dropdown Menu</h1>

  <div class="DropDownMenu">
    <button class="DropDownBottom">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="DropDownMenu-Content">
      <a href="">First</a>
      <a href="">Second</a>
      <a href="">Third</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helpful.